# How to find the IP adress of computer with which I am sharing the Internet

Tags: router, lan

I have one router with two PCs connected to it, via a LAN cable. Is there a way for me to find the IP address of the other PC?

Comment: Nmap does host discovery. https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html

Comment: home networking? you can ask this on the Super User stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a program called `netscan`, it scans your network and returns all of your devices connected to the network including the IP address.

Check it out here:
https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/

Ther's also apps on your cell phone you can use.

Comment: Odds are it's one IP address away from yours.  If you're 192.168.0.100, it is likely 192.168.0.101.

Answer (score 0):

netscan works fine.  If there are only two PCs connected to that router(I believe you mean a simple home router where all ports are in same LAN network), then you may just run wireshark or any packet capture tool in your PC and the chances are high that you would see some broadcast packets from the other PC. Source IP would be the other PCs IP.
OR, you can just login to router and check the DHCP client lists/ARP table.